# How to pass a variable in PHP from a Python file?

Tags: python, php, exec

I'm trying to call a Python script in a PHP file and pass a variable value from that script after pressing the submit button. I have it:

index.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form method="post">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    putenv("HOME=/");
    exec('python test.py'); 
    echo $x;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

test.py

```
 x = 'ass'
```

Both files are in the same folder. Why is it not working? I'd like to do this without Flask / Django.

Comment: PHP only sees the _output_ of your python script. It cannot see (and does not understand) any variables declared within the script. Remember they are two separate programs, in two separate languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare a variable in Python and use it directly in PHP after execution. Try to output your variable in Python:

```
x = 'test'    
print(x)
```

Now you can get the result of your script by the return value of the [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php) function:

```
$x = exec('python test.py'); 
echo $x;
```